# I have one issue on button click in ListView item

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` consisting of a button "Shortlist" , if someone clicks on that button the text of button should be changed. 
Button Shortlist inflation, where the shortlist[position].toString() value comes from server and if the button text is shortlisted then it will shown on button and button will not pressed. If the button text is shortlist then it will show on button as shortlist and button should be pressed.

Below is the my code.

```
public class Profile_Match_custom_List  extends ArrayAdapter<String>  {
private static final String url ="http://10.0.2.2/xp/shortlist1.php";
private static final String url1 = "http://10.0.2.2/xp/express_intrest.php";
private static final String KEY_MATRI_ID_TO="matriID_to";
private static final String KEY_MATRI_ID_BY="matriID_by";

SessionManager session;
public String matri_id_to, matri_id_by, str_gender;

String str;

public Button btnSort;
private NetworkImageView imageView;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private final String[] ids;
private String[] ages;
private String[] heights;
public String[] communities;
public String[] castes;
public String[] educations;
public String[] occupations;
public String[] incomes;
public String[] pics;
public String[] locations;
public String[] shortlist;
public String[] expressinterest;
private Activity context;


public Profile_Match_custom_List(Activity context, String[] ids, String[] ages,
                                 String[] heights, String[] communities, String[] castes,
                                 String[] educations, String[] occupations, String[]incomes,
                                 String[]pics, String[] locations, String[] shortlist, String[] expressinterest) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_profile_match,ids);
    this.ids = ids;
    this.ages = ages;
    this.heights = heights;
    this.communities = communities;
    this.castes = castes;
    this.educations = educations;
    this.occupations = occupations;
    this.incomes = incomes;
    this.pics = pics;
    this.locations = locations;
    this.shortlist = shortlist;
    this.expressinterest = expressinterest;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    final View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_profile_match, null, true);

    // Session class instance
    session = new SessionManager(getContext());
    session.checkLogin();

    // get user data from session
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    matri_id_by = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);
    str_gender = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_GENDER);

    String url1 = "https://www.maangal.com/thumb/thumb_";
    String url = url1 + pics[position];

    imageView = (NetworkImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.offer_image);
    imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this.getContext()).getImageLoader();
    if(str_gender.equals("Male")) {
        imageLoader.get(url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(imageView, R.drawable.image, R.drawable.girl));
    }
    else {
        imageLoader.get(url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(imageView, R.drawable.image, R.drawable.boy));
    }
    imageView.setImageUrl(url,imageLoader);
    TextView textViewId = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
    TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);

    textViewId.setText(ids[position]);
    textViewName.setText( ages[position]+" years"+" , "+heights[position]+" cm"+", "+communities[position]+" : "+castes[position]+" , "+educations[position]+" , "+occupations[position]+" , "+incomes[position]+", "+locations[position]);


    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), BlankActivity.class);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), ids[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            i.putExtra("id", ids[position]);
            v.getContext().startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    /*Button Shortlist inflation, where the shortlist[position].toString() 
    value comes from server and if the button text is shortlisted then it 
    will shown on button and button will not pressed. If the button text is 
    shortlist then it will show on button as shortlist and button should be 
    pressed.*/  


    btnSort =(Button) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btnshort);
    str = shortlist[position].toString();
    Log.e("------shortlisted------",str);
    if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("shortlisted")) {
        btnSort.setText(str);
        btnSort.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF307668"));
        btnSort.setEnabled(false);
  }
   else
   {
       btnSort.setText(str);
  }
    btnSort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            matri_id_to=ids[position];
            shortlist();
        }
    });




    Button btnChat =(Button) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btnchat);
    btnChat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            matri_id_to=ids[position];
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"sent express intrest",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            express_Intrest();
        }
    });

    Button declineButton = (Button)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.declineButton);
    declineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });
    return listViewItem;
}

  //shortlist method.
 private void shortlist(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>     () {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("***short response----",response.trim());
            if(response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                btnSort.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF307668"));
                btnSort.setText("shortlisted");
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "shortlisted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                btnSort.setEnabled(false);

            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_BY,matri_id_by);
            params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_TO,matri_id_to);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

public void express_Intrest(){
    StringRequest stringRequest1 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url1, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            Log.e("response",response);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_BY,matri_id_by);
            params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_TO,matri_id_to);

            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest1);
  }
 }
```

Comment: is `btnSort.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF307668"));` working ? any other error in Log ?

Comment: can you please pass the button as parameter to shortlist and do the same? That should work. I guess you are doing this from the adapter of the list view...

Comment: show full code.

Comment: btnSort.setBackgroundColor is also not working

Comment: Is `setEnabled(false)` working?

Comment: Are you doing it in the getview of the listadapter?

Comment: make sure that onResponse method's if condition getting true.. :D

Comment: @VikasGodiyal show `str` please

Comment: I have edited my code please check that. @Amiya str value comes from server.

Comment: @V.J if condition is true because toast is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not refreshing your list data. Save the position where click has been done then get or put data according to this position.

```
btnSort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        matri_id_to=ids[position]; //You can totally discard this line as you can get this value directly on getParams from selectedPosition.
        selectedPosition = position;
        shortlist();
    }
});
```

//shortlist method.

```
private void shortlist(){
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>     () {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.e("***short response----",response.trim());
        if(response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {

            shortlist[selectedPosition] = "shortlisted";
            notifyDataSetChanged(); //this will refresh your list and your code for disabling the button will work
        }
    }
},
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_BY,matri_id_by);
        params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_TO,matri_id_to);
        return params;
    }
};
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Once you do `shortlist[selectedPosition] = "shortlisted"` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` your adapter will refresh and getView will be called.  Your if..else code to set your btnSort will then work and will find selectedPosition in shortlist array as "shortlisted" and will produce your intended output.

Comment: Thank you sir it is working for me. and can you tell me what is use of this (shortlist[selectedPosition] = "shortlisted")

Comment: Added some explanation in edit. If you fond answer as helpful please mark as accept and useful.

Comment: what is shortlist[selectedPosition] = "shortlisted" which you took in onResponse method.

Comment: There is one error when I login with another used ID. The error is                       FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.devbhoomimedia.mgltest, PID: 8434
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: That's the different issue. Is it crashing on adapter? Then check for null and then perform setadapter or manipulating with it.

Comment: Can't predicate issue with just seeing type of exception. Basically whatever android runtime is trying to access after login is getting null. Need to see your code and proper stack trace. Post another question and comment its link.